# Dropdown menu keeps skipping away

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am creating some websites and I am always using the same dropdown method for them. However i am stuck with my dropdown menu. When I hover on it it always replaces my main navigation and well lets say that not so customer friendly.

The problem probably lies within the position values I give in my css code but I fail to find how to make the right values for my needs.

So in proper words, my navigation is fine till you hover over one with a dropdown menu then it replaces himself.

I included a **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r3gra7ta/1/)** to show you what i mean. There is a dropdown menu under the second link in the main navigation.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
  <div class="blueborder">
  </div>
  <section class="nav">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="main-nav" id="drop-nav">
        <li class="home-active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li> / </li>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="familiebedrijf.html">Over Ons</a></li>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <li><a href="betuigenissen.html">Betuigenissen</a></li>
          </div>
        </div>
        <li> / </li>
        <li><a href="schilderwerken.html">Schilderwerken</a></li>
        <li> / </li>
        <li><a href="behangwerken.html">Behangwerken</a></li>
        <li> / </li>
        <li><a href="raamdecoratie.html">Raamdecoratie</a></li>
        <li> / </li>
        <li><a href="realisaties.html">Realisaties</a></li>
        <li> / </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contacteer ons</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    position: inherit;
    background-color: #2C2A26;
    margin-top: 40px;
    color: #000;
    list-style: none;
    width: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 998;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-content li a {
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #ed5d00;
}
.dropdown-content li {
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
.dropdown-content li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #ed5d00;
}
/* Main Navi */

.main-nav {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 110%;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
.main-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1px;
    color: #fff;
}
.main-nav li a {
    padding: 8px 0;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 90%;
    border: 0;
}
.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active {
    color: #8dcee6;
}
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant CSS in the question too, please?

Comment: @Jay Sorry forgot to paste it. Its in there now. Also i gave a fiddle :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to `position: absolute;` on the `.dropdown-content` and remove the top-margin, works for me:

CSS:

```
.dropdown-content {
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    position: inherit;
    background-color: #2C2A26;
    color: #000;
    list-style: none;
    width: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 998;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r3gra7ta/2/

Comment: I kinda used the top margin so the menu pops down under my navigation balk. So when I use what you said it works but it has to be lower you see what i mean?

Comment: @Pixelsquare you can just add in a `margin-top` value and it should still work

Answer (score 1):

i think Your Navigation is a little bit confused.
One of simplest method is to set the submenu within the OVER ONS

```
      <li name="OVER ONS" ><li SUBITEM1 ></li><li SUBITEM2 ></li></li>
```

Here a Basic Example .

```css
#primary_nav_wrap
{
 margin-top:15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
 display:block;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:32px;
 padding:0 15px;
 font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
 background:#ddd
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
 background:#f6f6f6
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
 float:none;
 width:200px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
 top:0;
 left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
 display:block
}
```

```html
<h1>LOGO</h1>
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>
  <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">OVERONS</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Betuigenissen</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Schilderwerken</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Behangwerken</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Raamdecoratie</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Realisaties</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contacteer ons</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the postion to "fixed" and remove margin-top in dropdown-content then it will work fine.

```
    .dropdown-content {
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    position: inherit;
    background-color: #2C2A26;
    color: #000;
    list-style: none;
    width: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 998;
}
```

Comment: explain a bit more with some example or fiddle